# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS -- Cannot Disable IPV6

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-18.04

1. I want to disable ipv6 on my private GCP cloud network. I have no need for it on my internal network since Google terminates ipv6 at the GCP load balancer, so I edited /etc/sysctl.conf

   ```
   # disable ipv6
   net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
   net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
   net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
   net.ipv6.conf.ens4.disable_ipv6 = 1
   ```

of course sudo /etc/sysctl -p

2. Edited /etc/default/grub as follows:

sudo vi /etc/default/grub
Modified the GRUB_CMDLINEs to look like:

```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1"
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
```

Then executed:

sudo update-grub
sudo reboot

3. After reboot, sudo ps -ae | grep ip shows:

   ```
   ps -ae | grep ip  
   87 ?        00:00:00 ipv6_addrconf
   ```

WHY IS THIS IPV6 PROCESS RUNNING?

4. netstat -a shows

   ```
   tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
   udp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*                          
   udp        0      0 haproxy.fr:bootpc       0.0.0.0:*                          
   udp        0      0 localhost:323           0.0.0.0:*                          
   udp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:323       [::]:*                             
   raw6       0      0 [::]:ipv6-icmp          [::]:*
   ```

I edited sshd_config and removed the ipv6 listener address. This stops SSH from listening on an ipv6 address. Still doesn't answer #3 above.

5. sudo dmesg | grep IP

   ```
   [    0.012014] Calibrating delay loop (skipped) preset value.. 4400.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=8800000)  
   [    0.056601] smpboot: Total of 1 processors activated (4400.00 BogoMIPS)
   [    0.201233] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4 CALIPSO
   [    0.471145] Segment Routing with IPv6
   [    3.875631] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens4: link is not ready
   ```
6. cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6  produces: "1" which in THEORY says ipv6 is disabled. But I'm not sure if ipv6 is fully disabled per #3 above. Can someone tell me what #3 above means?

NOTE: IPV4 is running fine.

Comment: more information: sudo cat /proc/net/sockstat6  

        TCP6: inuse 0
        UDP6: inuse 1
        UDPLITE6: inuse 0
        RAW6: inuse 1
        FRAG6: inuse 0 memory 0

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you actually did disable IPV6 by editing sysctl.

By default, `ip a` on a stock Ubuntu 18.04 image returns this:

```
[...]
2: ens4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether [REDACTED] brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet [REDACTED]/32 scope global dynamic ens4
       valid_lft 86257sec preferred_lft 86257sec
    inet6 [REDACTED]/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However, after:

```
printf "\nnet.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1\nnet.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1\nnet.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1\nnet.ipv6.conf.ens4.disable_ipv6 = 1\n">> /etc/sysctl.conf

sysctl -p
```

With `ip a`, you should see this instead:

```
[...]
2: ens4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether [REDACTED] brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet [REDACTED]/32 scope global dynamic ens4
       valid_lft 85786sec preferred_lft 85786sec
```

Note that the whole `inet6` section is gone now.

Ironically, I encountered [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1771222) while testing. The workaround would be to add sysctl -p as a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/setting-metadata-and-startup-scripts) to the instance.

Regarding the `ipv6_addrconf` process, it's a system process, and disabling the module using modprobe doesn't seem to do much to get rid of it:

```
modprobe --remove ipv6
```

[Blacklisting it](https://askubuntu.com/a/499485) doesn't get rid of it either.

I would advise against this generally because that process is just sitting there doing nothing, and you're potentially running into kernel issues by tampering with it, especially if you're not sure what it does. The only decent article I found going in depth about the IPv6 module [is this one](http://www.telecom.otago.ac.nz/tele301/student_html/v6bootcamp-enable-disable.html). Your network interfaces wouldn't be using IPv6 anyway.